# Data attribute value is not passed in jquery var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following issue.
I'm generating multiple data from db and each item has a "delete" btn which has a "data-entryid" attribute with the entry id number.

I want to pass the data attribute of each item when i click the trash icon but with the current js code i only get the first entry's id.

Here's my html btn code where "entry-num" the entry id generated from db:

```
<a href="#" id="dlt-btn" data-entryid="{entry-num}" class="btn btn-danger delete">
   <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
</a>
```

And here's my js code in which i'm trying (for now) to pass the value in console:

```
$("#dlt-btn").click(function(){
 var entryId = $(this).data("entryid");
 console.log(entryId);
});
```

Comment: `id` attribute should be unique per page.

Comment: Oh i see! Thank you for your clarification!

Answer (score 3):

> The [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).

Use *class* instead of *id*:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
  var entryId = $(this).data("entryid");
  console.log(entryId);
});
```

Comment: Oh! It worked! Any explainations on why this happens when i use id?! (To avoid making the same silly mistake again)

Comment: @HarrysR., in a document `id` should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Use Class instead of Id Because its unique or  generated id

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the data is being generated after the page has loaded, you should try event delegation. Something like:

```
$('#someParentElement').on('click', '.deleteButtonClass', function(){
 var entryId = $(this).data("entryid");
 console.log(entryId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply like this use class instead id and change accordingly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dlt-btn").click(function(){
 var entryId = $(this).data("entryid");
 alert(entryId);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" data-entryid="value" class="btn btn-danger delete dlt-btn">
   <i class="far fa-trash-alt">ddd</i>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> if you do not want to use class and id Attributes.

```
$("a").on('click',function(){
    var entryId = $(this).data("entryid");
    console.log(entryId);
});
```